# Enviar datos al servidor que utiliza multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, multer, multipart

Estoy haciendo ciertas pruebas con Postman para enviar datos y archivos a mi servidor y así probar la API. Los archivos los envío usando multipart/form-data pero tengo un problema.

Uso un middleware creado con express-validator para verificar que los datos estén completos, el problema surge cuando dicho middleware es llamado antes que multer, el cuerpo de la solicitud (req.body) al momento de ser validado siempre está vacío incluso teniendo la certeza de que los datos están siendo proporcionados. Estos datos solo son recibidos por el servidor si utilizo json o urlencoded.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que ese middleware de validación pueda ser llamado antes que multer y así usar multipart/form-data desde Postman?.

Nota: necesito que ese middleware sea llamado antes que multer ya que algunos datos de body son usados para subir dichos archivos.

**Esta es la información del middleware de validación**

```
const { body } = require("express-validator");
const { validateResult } = require("../helpers/validateHelper");

const validateAddWord = [
  body(
    ["spanish", "kankuamo", "english", "category"],
    "Please insert complete data to save",
  ).notEmpty(),
  (req, res, next) => {
    validateResult(req, res, next);
  },
];
```

**Esta es la configuración usada para multer**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const { category } = req.body;

    //Validate if it is an image, sound or icon user
    switch (file.fieldname) {
      case "image":
        cb(null, join(__dirname, `../../public/images/${category}`));
        break;
      case "logo":
        cb(null, join(__dirname, `../../public/users/logo`));
        break;
      default:
        cb(
          null,
          join(__dirname, `../../public/sounds/${file.fieldname}/${category}`),
        );
    }
  }
```

**La ruta donde es llamado**

```
router.post("/", validateAddWord, sendData, createNewWord);
```

sendData hacer referencia a multer (el middleware proporcionado por este).

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba lo mismo y logre solucionarlo creando un middleware para borrar archivos con el metodo `unlink` de `fs` luego importe ese middleware de elmininar a mi middleware de validacion y si tenia un error comprobaba que el archivo ya existia con el metodo `access` y si existia el archivo y tenia un error en mi validacion eliminaba el archivo subido, de lo contrario continuaba a la proxima funcion en la ruta. Asi solucione ese problema ya que se me hizo imposible validar antes de subir el archivo. Espero que te sirva!!